# How to retrain a keras model on regular interval

Tags: keras, deep-learning, time-series, artificial-intelligence, lstm

Suppose I have 4000 data points at initial and I trained a model using data points from index 0 to 3999 then saved the model. Now after 5 days I loaded the saved model and now I used data from index 5 to 4004 to retrain the saved model. Do the training start from the last learned weights or the weights will be reinitialized as it happens in the fresh model? The data is time-series data.

Comment: That depends on what your code does exactly, there is no general answer because both options are possible in Keras

Comment: Can you provide the option in with which i can preserve the previous learning and later learning both.

Answer (score 0):

If the layers aren't frozen, the weights will update every time you start training, irrespective of the data point you choose to re-train from. Hence, the infomation for the weights in the previosuly saved model will be lost.

But if you choose to freeze some layers (and leave the others as they are), the frozen layers will retain the information of weights that were accquired from the previous training (datapoints 0 to 3999) and all other layers will update the weights according to the new data (datapoints 5 to 4004)